# How do I update Content Type Templates with REST api v2.1

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, sharepoint-rest-api

I have created a Content Type in SharePoint Online, through the Content Type Hub/Content Type Gallery, and uploaded a Word Document as it's Template.

What I am trying to do now is to update that Template (via Power Automate) whenever it's matching counterpart in a Controlled Documents library is edited and approved. According to this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCoc26aHHIw (Intro to Taxonomy and Content Type REST APIs) there was a new set of endpoints released last year where you can update the Content Type Template and re-publish the Content Type, however, I can't find any documentation regarding specifically updating the Template.

Does anyone have any info that might shed light on which REST endpoint to use? At the moment, I've hit a bit of a dead end so any help is appreciated. Thanks